# How does kotlin set generic parameters through the full class name?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I encapsulate `workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork` into a function.

```kotlin
object workUtils{
  fun enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(workManager: WorkManager,  work: Work){
    when (work.id) {
      1 -> enqueueUniquePeriodicWorkImpl<DoSomeThingWork1>(
        workManager = workManager,
        work = work
      )
      // more code...
      else -> enqueueUniquePeriodicWorkImpl<DoSomeThingWork2>(
        workManager = workManager,
        work = work
      )
    }
  }
  private inline fun <reified W : ListenableWorker> enqueueUniquePeriodicWorkImpl(
    workManager: WorkManager,
    work: Work
  ) {
    // The internal implementation of this function is not important
    workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
      work.title,
      ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.UPDATE,
      PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<W>(
        work.repeatInterval,
        TimeUnit.valueOf(work.repeatIntervalTimeUnit)
      )
        .setInputData(
          workDataOf(
            "workId" to work.id.toString(),
          )
        )
        .setConstraints(
          Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)
            .build()
        )
        .setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()
    )
  }
}
```

I want to set this `<W>` generic parameter by the full class name, but I don't know how to do it? Pseudocode `Type(work.className)` similar to the following:

```kotlin
workUtils.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork<Type(work.className)>( workManager, work)
```

Or there are other ways to avoid writing so many cases?

###### first edit 2023-3-16

`PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder`

```kotlin
public inline fun <reified W : ListenableWorker> PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder(
    repeatInterval: Long,
    repeatIntervalTimeUnit: TimeUnit
): PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder {
    return PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(W::class.java, repeatInterval, repeatIntervalTimeUnit)
}
```

Comment: @Sweeper 1.`PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<W>` is provided by the Android class, but generics are its requirements, I added the code of `PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder`, it's a inline fun. 2. Maybe I don’t know much. In my opinion, `<W>` is a generic parameter, and passing in a specific class is to set the generic parameter, like `enqueueUniquePeriodicWorkImpl<DoSomeThingWork1>`

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry, I don't know how to replace `<reified W : ListenableWorker>` with `KClass<in ListenableWorker>`, can you please provide some code?

Comment: @Sweeper passing `W::class.java` shouldn't work, it's just an idea, I want to set `W` by full class name somehow. Actually, what I need is a solution that eliminates `case` related code, so other solutions are also possible.

Comment: @Sweeper `PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<DoSomeThingWork1>(...)` This is the function used directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generics here are kind of forcing you to write so many cases, when you don't need the generics at all, because `PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder` really just need a `Class<out ListenableWorker>`.

You can change the private `Impl` method to:

```
  private fun enqueueUniquePeriodicWorkImpl(
    // add this parameter
    workerClass: Class<out ListenableWorker>,
    workManager: WorkManager,
    work: Work
  ) {
    
    workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
      work.title,
      ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.UPDATE,
      // use the builder with the dot in between, instead of your wrapper
      PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
        workerClass, // pass the class here
        work.repeatInterval,
        TimeUnit.valueOf(work.repeatIntervalTimeUnit)
      )
      // ...
    )
  }
```

Then the caller can do:

```
val workerClass: Class<out ListenableWorker> = when (work.id) {
    1 -> DoSomeThingWork1::class.java
    2 -> DoSomeThingWork2::class.java
    else -> DoSomeThingWork2::class.java
}
enqueueUniquePeriodicWorkImpl(workerClass, workManager, work)
```

That's still a lot of cases. To improve this further, you can store the class as a property of `Work`:

```
// have this instead of your className property
val workerClass: Class<out ListenableWorker>
```

and just set this when you create a `Work`, or whenever you set the `id`. Then you won't even need a `Impl` method. Just directly call `enqueueUniquePeriodicWork`:

```
workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
      work.title,
      ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.UPDATE,
      PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder<W>(
        work.workerClass, // you can get the class directly from the work parameter
        work.repeatInterval,
        TimeUnit.valueOf(work.repeatIntervalTimeUnit)
      )
      // ...
```

Alternatively, just put everything in a `Map` and make a `Map<Int, Class<out ListenableWorker>>`.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have expressed myself clearly. What I want is to eliminate `case` related code, no select statement,using `map` doesn't really serve the purpose. My idea is that if in your example the fully qualified class name is somehow converted to `DoSomeThingWork1::class.java`.

Comment: @FreedomFoolt Sure, if you *really* want, you can do `Class.forName(work.className)` (assuming `className` is fully qualified), that's reflection, and there are better alternatives out there, like just storing the `Class`.

Comment: 1.I just tested it and it worked. It seems that this is unique to the builder mode. If a class does not provide a builder constructor, is it possible to set the generic type through `className`? like `Response<T>` 2. You seemed to have a different perspective on my question before, now that you understand what I mean, can you give a suggestion on modifying the title of this question?

Comment: @FreedomFoolt As I said, you should not use generics here. Pass `Class`es. Store a `Class` in `Work` and pass that, or pass `Class.forName(work.className)` to the builder if you really want. And no, I don't "have a different perspective on your question before". My perspective has not changed.

Comment: I know `not use generics here.` But suppose this class does not provide `builder`, and it also requires passing in generics, can this solution still be used?

Comment: @FreedomFoolt no, but the burden is on you to show me an actual scenario like that (and you should post this as another question), and then I can potentially give you another solution.

Comment: This is awkward, I know the use scenario, but I can't think of another title.